# Extra layer for communication from client to Service via client ->Api->ESB->Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, architecture, microservices, esb

We are architecting a new system where ESB is the centerline channel for service communication. as we don't want our HTML/js client to interact with a bus directly, so we decided to introduce Api (ReST-API) layer where the client will post request to Api than API will put a message in ESB and respective service will subscribe for that particular message and will process it.

so it will be like
  UI -> Rest -> ESB -> Service

As I knew no other services will not be interested in this particular message. so just wondering cant we do below??

UI->Rest-> Service and keep ESB used for only inter-service communications not from UI to service path. considering there will be 1000's of UI to service communication.

Comment: To further understand your question, what is the difference between "Rest" and "Service" in your question. Ideally a backend Service could be a REST service or SOAP service or Graph QL service etc, basically the way you expose your service.

Comment: you can consider Rest is just a gateway to the client, it doesn't have any business logic, its responsibility is limited to request validation, authentication and build a response, once validated it will pass the request to service for further processing mainly business logic.

Comment: Okay, it all depends on how many subscribers(services) would need this message that is coming from UI. As of now you have identified just one service that needs this data. Introducing an ESB layer would decouple the "Rest" and "Service" layers and in the future if there are more services needing this message, a little change in ESB layer would be sufficient to meet your future needs without disturbing the "Rest" and "Service". Without ESB, you end-up in a tightly coupled pattern. Also, if the service is enhanced in the future, ESB could play a role in data transformation.

Comment: Please comment if this info. helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how many subscribers(services) would need this message that is coming from UI. As of now you have identified just one service that needs this data. Introducing an ESB layer would decouple the "Rest" and "Service" layers and in the future if there are more services needing this message, a little change in ESB layer would be sufficient to meet your future needs without disturbing the "Rest" and "Service". Without ESB, you end-up in a tightly coupled pattern. Also, if the service is enhanced in the future, ESB could play a role in data transformation.